# Bound Involving Submartingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $(X_{j})_{j \geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables with $X_{j}$ having mean zero and a finite moment generating function $\phi_{j}(\xi) = E(e^{\xi X_{j}})$ for all $\xi$ in a neighborhood $J$ of zero, $j \geq 1$.

Define $S_{n} = X_{1} + \dots X_{n}$, $Z_{n} = e^{\xi S_{n}}/\prod_{j=1}^{n} \phi_{j}(\xi)$, $M_{n} = \max\{S_{1}, \dots, S_{n}\}$, $m_{n} = \min\{S_{1}, \dots, S_{n}\}$.

Note that $Y_{n} = e^{\xi S_{n}}$ is a submartingale for every $\xi \in J$.
Show that for all $\lambda > 0$, $$P(M_{n} \geq \lambda) \leq e^{-\xi \lambda} \prod_{j=1}^{n} \phi_{j}(\xi), \ \xi > 0, \ \xi \in J$$
and $$P(m_{n} \leq -\lambda) \leq e^{\xi \lambda} \prod_{j=1}^{n} \phi_{j}(\xi), \ \xi < 0, \ \xi \in J.$$

I tried to apply Doob's maximal inequality to $Y_{n}$ but I couldn't derive the expressions wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: (For $\xi > 0$) (I am assuming $X_i$ are independent).

1) $$\{M_n \geq \lambda\} \iff \{e^{\xi M_n} \geq e^{\xi\lambda }\}$$

2) $$e^{\xi M_n} = e^{\xi \max_i S_i} = \max_i e^{\xi S_i} = \max_i Y_i$$

Can you take it from here? Let me know if you need additional help.

**Update:** For the next park, work with $-X_i$. Then $T_n =-S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n -X_i$. And $T_n$ is a martingale. As you mentioned in comments,
$$-m_n = \max\{-S_1,-S_2,\cdots, -S_n\}= \max\{T_1,T_2,\cdots, T_n\}$$

You can, using the logic above, show
$$P[m_n \leq -\lambda]= P[-m_n \geq \lambda]= P[e^{-m_n\xi} \geq e^{\lambda \xi}]$$
(Here $\xi > 0$). Noting that $e^{T_n\xi}$ is a submartingale.
$$P[e^{-m_n\xi} \geq e^{\lambda \xi}] \leq E[e^{T_n\xi}] e^{-\xi\lambda}= E[e^{-S_n\xi}] e^{-\xi\lambda}$$
Now replace $\xi$ with $-\xi$

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I was trying similar things too. I have no idea about the second part though...

Comment: Don't worry about the second part. What happens when you multiply a negative number ($\xi$) on both sides of $\{m_n \leq -\lambda\}$?

Comment: Thanks. One question though. To get to the final expression, we need $E(\prod_{j} e^{\xi X_{j}}) = \prod_{j} E(e^{\xi X_{j}})$. But $X_{j}$ are not independent. So how to justify this?

Comment: Oh. I didn't see that. Give me some time to see if I can fix it. Also could you tell me the source of this problem?

Comment: It's a homework problem for my stochastic process class.

Comment: Wait. A key aspect of applying Doob's Inequality here is that $S_n$ is a martingale, which I know is true when $X_i$ are iid mean zero. But here $E[S_n|S_{n-1}] = S_{n-1} + E[X_n |S_{n-1}]$. In iid case $E[X_n |S_{n-1}] = E[X_n] =0$. But we can't conclude this when they are not iid.

Comment: I thought about that too. There might be a typo in the problem. For the second part though, is there a way to link the min and max? Like $min(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}) = -max(-X_{1}, \dots, -X_{n})$? I still don't quite get it yet.